# $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\sin^5\theta\cos^4\theta \,\mathrm d\theta=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^5\theta\cos^4\theta \,\mathrm d\theta$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My instructor wrote

> $$\int_0^\pi\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4(\theta) \,\mathrm d\theta\tag{1}$$
> $$=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4(\theta) \,\mathrm d\theta\tag{2}$$
> $$=2\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5+1}{2}\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{4+1}{2}\right)}{2\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{5+1}{2}+\frac{4+1}{2}\right)}\\=\frac{16}{315}.$$

How did he know that going from step $(1)$ to $(2)$ is valid? We can vaguely verify the step by checking the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n7cfnou6yg), which he had not seen.

Comment: Symmetry. Sine is the same on the left half of $[0,\pi]$ as is on the right half, and cosine is the opposite, but minus signs go away when you perform even powers. These facts show up over and over and over again, so your instructor was already familiar with this common trick.

Comment: Notice that $\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is an even function while $\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is an odd function; raising the former to a natural power and the latter to an even power gives even functions; the product of two even functions gives an even function; so $\sin^5\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos^4\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is an even function; so, $x=\frac{\pi}2$ is a line of symmetry of $\sin^5\left(x\right)\cos^4\left(x\right).$

Comment: @ryang Hi sensei :-) Isn't $x=0$ supposed to be **the** line of symmetry for even functions? What I mean is, an even function necessarily only has **one** line of symmetry ($x=0$). So, does $\sin^5\theta\cos^4\theta$ being an even function have importance to it being symmetric about $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Where did you see the claim even functions only have one line of symmetry?  In contrast, it's true that if a function has more than one vertical line of symmetry, it's periodic; and if a periodic function has at least one vertical line of symmetry, then it has infinitely many.  This happens all the time with the standard trig functions.

Comment: Hey tryingtobeastoic. Any function $f$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ is, by definition, an even function; so, for example, $\cos$ is even; and, proving Brian's above assertions involves invoking this property. P.S. That full-stop that you edited away was actually correct to be there!

Comment: @BrianMoehring No, you misunderstood. I meant that even functions must have **at least** one line of symmetry at $x=0$ (if the function is a function of x). "*and if a periodic function has at least one vertical line of symmetry, then it has infinitely many*". Thank you, I did not know that.

Comment: @ryang edited the full-stop back!

Comment: It might be also mentioned that these symmetries  get us the "communtation" of exponents $$ 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4(\theta) \ \ d\theta\ \ \ = \ \ 2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4(\theta)\cos^5(\theta) \ \ d\theta\ $$ $$ = \ \frac{\Gamma\left( 3 \right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac52\right)}{ \Gamma\left( \frac{11}{2}\right)} \ \ = \ \ \mathbf{B}  \left(3 \ , \ \frac52 \right) \ \ = \ \  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac52 \right) · \Gamma\left( 3 \right) }{ \Gamma\left( \frac{11}{2}\right)} \ \ = \ \ \mathbf{B}  \left(\frac52 \ , \ 3 \right) \ \ . $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that
$$\int_0^{2a} f(x)dx=2\int_0^af(x)dx$$

if $f(a+x)=f(a-x)$
here $f(\theta)=\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4\theta$

Check $f(\pi/2+\theta)=f(\pi/2-\theta)$.

So, $$\int_0^{{2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}}}\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4(\theta)d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^5(\theta)\cos^4(\theta)d\theta$$

Rest is just application of [Walli's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833731/reduction-formula-for-integral-sinm-x-cosn-x-with-limits-0-to-pi-2).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833731/reduction-formula-for-integral-sinm-x-cosn-x-with-limits-0-to-pi-2 , here's the link to refer the Wallis formula

Answer (score 1):

Alternative explanation:
$$\begin{align}\int_{\frac\pi 2}^{\pi}\sin^5\theta\cos^4\theta d\theta
&\overset{\theta\rightarrow\theta+\frac\pi 2}{=}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin^5(\theta+\frac\pi 2)\cos^4(\theta+\frac\pi 2)d(\theta+\frac\pi 2)\\
&\overset{\theta\rightarrow\frac\pi 2-\theta}{=}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\cos^5\theta\sin^4\theta d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\sin^5\theta\cos^4\theta d\theta
\end{align}$$